Work done by using PV graph

One mole of an ideal monoatomic gas is subjected to changes as shown in the graph. What will be the magnitude of work done, in Joules?


I know that work done $=$ area inside cyclic process
Therefore, the work done should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{4} \times 100$ (because this is one fourth of a circle of radius 1). The answer is to be given in Joules, thus multiplying by 100. But this is not the answer.
Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

It is not a part of a circle, but a part of a hyperbole, p[bar] = 40 [bar . L] / V[L].

Stages:
($\ce{1 -> 2})=\mathrm{isobaric\;expansion}$
($\ce{2 -> 3})=\mathrm{isochoric\;cooling}$
($\ce{3 -> 1})=\mathrm{isothermal\;compression}$
Work per stage:
$W_{1,2}=-P_1\;\Delta V_{1,2}=-(\pu{1bar})(\pu{20L})=\pu{-20bar\;L}=\pu{-2000J}$
$W_{2,3}=0$
$W_{3,1}=-P_3V_3\ln\left(\frac{V_1}{V_3}\right)=-(\pu{0.5bar})(\pu{40L})\ln\left(\frac{\pu{20L}}{\pu{40L}}\right)=\pu{13.86bar\;L}=\pu{1386J}$
Work of process:
$W=W_{1,2}+W_{2,3}+W_{3,1}=\left(-2000+0+1386\right)\pu{J}=\pu{-614J}$
Since $W$ is negative in this case, according to the IUPAC sign convention, this particular process performs $\pu{614J}$ of work.

Even though the temperatures at the end points 3-->1 are the same, that does not guarantee that the temperature is constant between the ends.

@ChetMiller There is strictly insufficient information given to determine isothermal or otherwise for $\ce{3->1}$; however, I seriously doubt a HS level assignment on Thermodynamics would use a complex trajectory (such as a segment of an elipse) rather than a common one like an isothermal compression. Furthermore, PV ends being equal hint at it being isothermal based on numerical agreement, while assuming an elipse is visually subjective since the graph is low quality and only an arbitrary segment is shown. I would respectfully say the former analysis is more reliable than the latter.

The work you have calculated is only the surface of the "round triangle" under the arc 3 → 1 taken as "round hypotenuse", with a base at $\pu{0.5 bar}.$ The integral defining the work is more important. It is equal to the sum of this "round triangle" plus the area of the square under the pressure $\pu{0.5 bar},$ taken between $\pu{20 L}$ and $\pu{40 L}.$ This area is equal to $(\pu{40 L} - \pu{20 L})(\pu{0.5 bar}) = \pu{10 L bar}.$ Please give the result in joules.

Shouldn't the work done be JUST the area inside the cyclic process and nothing else? Why consider the area of square below the process?

The area of the "round triangle" is the integral of :  (P - $0.5$)dV. It is not the work.  The work is the integral of PdV.

The area of the "round triangle" is W = integral p.dV  along the closed process paths. the area below the section "1->2"  minus area below the curve "3->1"

It is like for the Carnot cycle, just different shape.

The cycle in the figure seems to be in the shape of 1/4 of an ellipse, with semi-major axis a = 20 L and semi-minor axis b = 0.5 bars.  The area of an ellipse is $A = \pi a b$.  So the work done by the gas in the cycle is $$W=\frac{\pi}{4}ab=\frac{\pi}{4}(20)(0.5)\ barL=2.5\pi\ barL=250\pi\ J=785\ J$$

with all due respect to the member who gave this answer a downvote, I stand by my answer.  I challenge anyone to point out any kind of error in this analysis.

I did not downvote, but all stands and falls with the graphical  interpretation of the chart. Elliptical curve would mean requirement of very special temperature control.

@Poutnik Even though PV at the end points is the same (and thus the temperature), the vertical tangent at the left end and the horizontal tangent at the right end suggest non-constant temperature.  Otherwise, the slopes of the PV curves would be different than these at the ends;  ellipse would be a better match.

Hmm, as the chart is not of a top quality, making conclusions based solely on the shape is not fully justified. But having the result for an alternative case does not make any harm.
